# Leaflet custom tiles sizing

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I am trying to show my own custom tiles and I am having trouble with the display of the tiles and their sizing.

The Entire game map is corresponding to x16384,y16384 
Which I confirmed with the imgaeOverlay, displaying the entire map from one image of 1024px/1024px which shows the entire map while dropping a tree to the correct coordinates.

But the resolution is terrible so I am trying to display it with tiles

[image]

But the tiles are displayed way too small. The first layer L7(zoom0) which is only one image is shown as one tiny image(tile) while zoom level 1(L6) is showing the 4 images of this level a bit closer.

Presumable cause it's showing 1/16 and 4/16 of a grid?
The tree is also way out of bounds with the tilelayer.
The count of my map source files(game files) goes up each zoom level (L7-L1) x*4 (1,4,16,64....)

**Question:** How can I change the grid pattern? So that the one image of zoom 0 and the 4 images of zoom level 1 both correspond to y16384 x16384 while taking 100isch% of my map div?

I had to change the map names from how you see them I'm above the image into the following folder/naming structure, maybe this is part of the issue?

- map/{1}/{0}/{0}.png
- map/{1}/{0}/{1}.png
- map/{1}/{1}/{0}.png
- map/{1}/{1}/{1}.png

```html
<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 7,
        tileSize: 1024,
        });
        
    var bounds = [[0,0], [16384,16384]];
    //var image = L.imageOverlay('map/source/MAP_L7_y000_x000.png', bounds).addTo(map);
    L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{y}/{x}.png').addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setView( [000, 000], 0);
    
    //test marker
    var tree = L.latLng([ 6231.0166015625, 10161.369140625 ]);
    L.marker(tree).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there is a mistake in setting `tileSize` option in map definition. It should be set in tile layer creation.

Second, since tiled layer is different in nature than image layer, it requires different approach. It's coordinates range (bounds) is `[[0, 0], [tileSize, tileSize]]`. If you want to use your range of `[[0, 0], [16384, 16384]]`, you have to use a transformed simple CRS, where every coordinate is multiplied by `tileSize / 16384`.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var tileSize = 1024;
var imageSize = 16384;
var factor = tileSize / imageSize;

L.CRS.myCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(factor, 0, factor, 0)
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.myCRS,
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 7,
});
    
L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
  tileSize: tileSize,
}).addTo(map);

var bounds = [[0,0], [imageSize, imageSize]];
map.fitBounds(bounds);

map.setView([imageSize / 2, imageSize / 2], 0);

var tree = L.latLng([6231.0166015625, 10161.369140625]);
L.marker(tree).addTo(map);
```

Coordinate order for Leaflet functions/methods in `L.CRS.Simple` projection is `[y, x]`. Origin `[0, 0]` is in upper left corner, `y` goes from top to bottom, `x` goes from left to right.

If you want to have origin `[0, 0]` at lower left corner and `y` going from bottom to top, CRS transform has to be a little different (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#transformation):

```
L.CRS.myCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(factor, 0, -factor, tileSize)
});
```

Comment: This is definitely more like I was expecting it. Though the test tree is at a completely different position now compared to when using imageOverlay. I changed L.Transformation(factor, 1, factor, 246) so it is very close to where it is supposed to be. But I assume the factor is wrong somehow. When I open the 1024px image the tree should be at pixel 634/634

Comment: Without having access to your tiles it's hard to say why it's not working for you as expected. See working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/rfgoe6m3/

Comment: I found the issue, the Y-axis is inverted compared to imageoverlay and source, which is why the test marker is placed correctly there but wrong on L.CRS.myCRS

Comment: If answer helped you solve your problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let other users with similar problems know that problem was resolved.

Comment: It's not solved, I know what the issue is, still testing mate

Comment: And what is not clear if you look at the above mentioned JSFiddle? Pointer coordinates are displayed live at the bottom left corner. Point [0, 0] is in the upper left corner, x coordinates go right and y coordinates down from there.

Comment: [0,0] on my source is bottom left, which makes my marker coordinates miss if it is not like that.

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: That looks, good, thanks. I guess I don´t understand the Transformation properly. Is there a proper source somewhere for leaflet that not only explains what attributes and classes are available but also explains what they are for, why and how one needs to use them? The official docs seem to be lacking a lot on that part

Comment: Apart from basic tutorials at https://leafletjs.com/examples.html I'm not aware of such site. But coordinate transformations are common GIS operations, not something specific to Leaflet. There are tons of them, this is one of the simplest affine transforms.